# video frame from videoinput

Tags: video, matlab, matlab-guide

I am new on MATLAB and i have to take input of real time video and track some object, i am using a function:

```
obj = videoinput('winvideo' ,1,'YUY2_320x240');
```

to take real time video and i have to read the 1st frames of video to track the object region i used

```
videoFileReader = read(video,1);
```

method but it gives an error

> Error: " Undefined function 'read' for input arguments of type 'videoinput'   "

so i need any alternative way to read first frame.

Comment: maybe look into preview and getsnapshot: http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/preview.html

Comment: Thanks for this, i used get-snapshot(), know my question is if i want to take a set of 30 frames i am using for loop, but it saves image by overlapping it on first one, how i can save a whole set ?